# ERROR Plugin load failed: hexo-asset-link

Tags: hexo

When I using this [hexo](https://hexo.io/) command to create a new draft, shows error:

```
> hexo new draft genie-ppt
INFO  Validating config
ERROR Plugin load failed: hexo-asset-link
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/chalk@5.3.0/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/hexo-asset-link/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/chalk@5.3.0/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js in /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/hexo-asset-link/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at req (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:285:23)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/hexo-asset-link/index.js:3:15
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:298:14
From previous event:
    at Hexo.loadPlugin (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:278:27)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/load_plugins.js:54:18
From previous event:
    at loadModules (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/load_plugins.js:52:6)
    at module.exports (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/load_plugins.js:11:10)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:244:36
From previous event:
    at Hexo.init (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/node_modules/.pnpm/hexo@6.0.0/node_modules/hexo/lib/hexo/index.js:239:20)
    at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/pnpm/global/5/.pnpm/hexo-cli@4.3.1/node_modules/hexo-cli/dist/hexo.js:47:21
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
INFO  Created: ~/source/reddwarf/frontend/reddwarftech.github.io/source/_drafts/genie-ppt-5.md
```

the draft create success, but how to fixed this plugin error? I have already tried to install the plugin like this:

```
pnpm i hexo-asset-link
```